# how to call click event in jQuery on background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please see below code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            ul li {
                BACKGROUND: url('Close.png');
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center;
                background-position: right;
                background-color: orange;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("li").click(function() {
                    var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
                    bg = bg.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '');
                    alert(bg);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:500px;">div (grandparent)
            <ul>
                <li>li (child) (grandchild)</li>
                <li>li (child) (grandchild)</li>
                <li>li (child) (grandchild)</li>
                <li>li (child) (grandchild)</li>
                <li>li (child) (grandchild)</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

### JSFiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/VFGsU/

If you see the above code then in variable "bg" I am getting url of the background image of the `li` element.

I want to call remove() method of jQuery on this url (i.e. on variable bg)....

Actually I want to achieve that when user click on this background image then that particular `li` has to get removed from `ul`.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: `$(this).css('background-image','');`

Comment: 'that perticular li has to get removed from ul.'? The `li` or the `background-image`?

Comment: Added a JSfiddle so people can play with this.

Answer (score 0):

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/VFGsU/2/)

**HTML**

enclose text of `li` inside `span`

```
<li><span>li (child) (grandchild)1</span></li>
```

**js**

```
$(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '');
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $('li span').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); //if click on text no action
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/VFGsU/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url(', '').replace(')', '');
        alert(bg);
        $(this).remove(); //remove clicked li
    });
});
```

Comment: @putvande : I want that when user clicks on background-image then that perticular li has to get removed from ul....if user is clicking somewhere else in li then that li should not get removed....so this li removal functionality should be binded to only to background image click.....

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to find if they happen to click the "location" of the background image inside the LI...this is much more complicated than if you just make a child tag and check to see if the child tag was clicked...as you have to test mouse position, etc.  However, if you have an inner tag inside the LI...it's fairly easy.  So, I would say that this is a better approach:

```
CSS
li > .remove { display:inline-block;width:20px;height:20px;
    background-image: close.png; }

HTML
<li data-toggle='remove'><span class='remove'></span></li>

JAVASCRIPT
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle=remove]', function(e) {
    var $clickedTag = $(e.target);
    if( $clickedTag.hasClass('remove') ) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
}
```

If you need to, make your LI position:relative, and your .remove class position:absolute, and you can position the closing button anywhere you want relative to the LI tag.